# Modify the contents of null columns in pandas by checking values in multiple colums

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How to obtain the below operation on dataframe easily in pandas using fewer steps?

Input:

```
di = {'col1': ['1', '2', '5',None, None,'10', None,None], 
  'col2': ['4', '7', None, '8', None, None, '11',None], 
  'col3': ['9', None, '3', '8', None,None, None,'12'],
  'col4': ['abc', 'def', 'ghi', 'jkl', None,'mno', 'pqr',None],
  'col5': ['123', None, '456', '789', None,None, None,'012'],
  }

df = pd.DataFrame(di, dtype=object)
```

***Input Dataframe:***

[image: embedded image]

***Required Ouput dataframe:***

[image: embedded image]

The method I used:

```
df.loc[~df.col1.isnull() & df.col2.isnull() & df.col3.isnull(), ['col2','col3']] = 'Hello'

df.loc[df.col1.isnull() & ~df.col2.isnull() & df.col3.isnull(), ['col1','col3']] = 'Hello'

df.loc[df.col1.isnull() & df.col2.isnull() & ~df.col3.isnull(), ['col1','col2']] = 'Hello'

df.loc[~df.col1.isnull() & ~df.col2.isnull() & df.col3.isnull(), ['col3']] = 'Hello'

df.loc[df.col1.isnull() & ~df.col2.isnull() & ~df.col3.isnull(), ['col1']] = 'Hello'

df.loc[~df.col1.isnull() & df.col2.isnull() & ~df.col3.isnull(), ['col2']] = 'Hello'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to apply it to those three columns:

```
cols = ['col1','col2','col3']
df[cols] = df[df.loc[:,cols].notnull().any(axis=1)][cols].fillna('Hello')
df = df.replace(dict({np.nan: None}))

print(df) 
    col1   col2   col3  col4  col5
0      1      4      9   abc   123
1      2      7  Hello   def  None
2      5  Hello      3   ghi   456
3  Hello      8      8   jkl   789
4   None   None   None  None  None
5     10  Hello  Hello   mno  None
6  Hello     11  Hello   pqr  None
7  Hello  Hello     12  None   012
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understood you correctly, but if you want replace all None values by "Hello" you could simply use:

```
df.fillna("Hello")
```

Answer (score 0):

`df.fillna('Hello', inplace=True)` . Use `inplace` wisely , read about it .

Answer (score 0):

IIUC:

You want to fill null values except when they are all null values for the row.

```
m = df.isna().all(1)
df.fillna(‘Hello’).mask(m, df, axis=0)
```

Answered from my phone

Comment: Thanks this works. But what I need is to restrict the filling of null values to these 3 columns even if there are other columns in the dataframe, (I have updated my question)